# How to have a splash screen image on Android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, image

I have a basic XML Android app. How can I have a image apear for the first couple seconds after the app is launched and then the main.xml page open?

Comment: There's already [tons of similar question asked](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=splash+screen+android&submit=search) on SO. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
TimerTask timerTask;
Timer timer;

timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.package.SECONDACTIVITY"));
            // change the Intent above to whatever your second activity is.
            finish();
        }
    };

timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timerTask, 1 * 1000); 
// change the 1 above to however many seconds you wanna display the splash
```